# Vector allocating too much memory

Tags: c++, vector

My std::Vector is allocation too much memory without any objects in it.

In header file:

```
std::vector<ge::Rect> m_Frames;
```

Now this should call the default constructor in the source file but just out of speculation, I did this in the class constructor:

```
m_Frames.reserve(10);
```

Now the Rect class is in a namespace of "ge" and it's a really simple class, in fact it was a struct and I turned it into a class while debugging this problem. It is 16 bytes in total, 4 integer values for making a rectangle.

Prior to any calls to "push_back" I print the capacity of the vector:

```
cout << m_Frames.capacity() << endl;
```

And I get incredibly large numbers. On the magnitude of 100 millions as if it's trying to allocate all available memory.  Any call to push_back causes bad_alloc exception. In case you're curious, the size of the Rect object is 16 bytes.

Edit:

It may be important to note that the capacity before the reserve is 0 and after it's 10. However, later in the code it's the enormous number.

Comment: Please add an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) along with compiler and flags.

Comment: you have stack corruption somewhere, check you places where you access vector or array. Probably you are writing out of bounds.

Comment: "later in the code"... oh, you mean the code you don't show us?

Comment: "However, later in the code it's the enormous number." That implies the vector is getting corrupted by a dodgy memory access, or destroyed while you still have a reference to it, or something along those lines. Use a debugger, or something like Valgrind, or reduce your program to the minimum required to reproduce the result and post that here.

Comment: Thanks Uldisk and Seymour, you're right. It appears that the destructor was called when it shouldn't be. I will dive into the rest of the code.

Comment: Seymour, can you make your response into an answer and I'll accept it please.

Comment: @Lostdev: Use "@name" syntax to reply to people so that they get notifications. 3½ years is sufficient time to learn the basics of this site.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sure thing captain.